# When to use html key in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In rails I've seen code like

```
form_for(@post, html: {:class => "foo"})
```

but sometimes rails auto converts any key it doesn't recognize to html?

In the above instance, if you don't use the `:html` key, the class assignment won't be reflected in the DOM.

when to use this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for) you should use the html option whenever you want to add attributes to the form tag:

":html - Optional HTML attributes for the form tag."

There are other pre-defined options that rails can pick up. There are quite a lot. You can see exactly which in [the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for).

Comment: so it's only used in conjunction with form_for?

Comment: I can't tell for sure. Each form helper defines its own options. I'm not familiar with any others that define an html option. I couldn't find any in a quick search, but this is very possible.

Answer (score 1):

Its just because rails form_for is defined such way ... you can always check api while passing correct options and their order.

http://api.rubyonrails.org#for_for